# unresolved external symbol when linking static library with Squish Coco + Scons + Visual Studio

Tags: code-coverage

I have set environment variables CC, LINK, AR. When linking static libraries, it hits many errors like:

XXX.lib(YYY.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___cs_tb_cqAX5_1FNfXC_1nA5FM_main_AAAA_BBBB_lib_CCC_DDDD_c

There is no problem for shared libraries. Is there some special setting for static library with Squish Coco? It works correctly without Squish Coco.

I am using Squish Coco 4.3.3.

I have tried to exclude relative source files by -cs-exclude-file-regex=(aa|bb|cc).* 
But it could not read correctly after |, it seems Scons' issue?

There is GENERATE_COVERAGESCANNER_LIBRARY in link.cspro, lib.cspro, cl.cspro, ar.cspro. Does it matter? How should I set them?

This is from Squish Coco document:

GENERATE_COVERAGESCANNER_LIBRARY=⟨YES/NO⟩:
If set, the CoverageScanner library is generated during the linking operation. This should be disabled when generating static libraries.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using the scons which is customized in our product. Is it possible because libpath is passed to scons too late so that Squish Coco could not get it?

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved by following steps:

1. search for link.cspro in the %SQUISHCOCO% directory (there are more than one).
2. edit it and replace the line:

LIBRARY_PATH_OPTION=/LIBPATH:;-LIBPATH:

through:

LIBRARY_PATH_OPTION=/LIBPATH:;-LIBPATH:;/libpath:;-libpath:

Then resume the build.

The reason is in the LINKFLAGS "/libpath:" is used, However Froglogic Squish Coco handle only "/LIBPATH:".